# Would removing a domain-verification tag specific to a social media platform (Facebook) have negative effects on SEO?

Tags: seo, domains, facebook, social-media, twitter

Our company previously had a Facebook page, complete with FB business and advertising account, so naturally, years ago, I installed a `facebook-domain-verification` tag on the website using a `TXT` record in the domain DNS

But now, given Facebook's recent stance on data privacy, perceptions have shifted, and our company recently decided to distance ourselves from FB and ramp up our presence on Twitter instead. **As a result, we scheduled our company Facebook page for deletion and deactivated the associated business accounts. With that in mind, are there any unforeseen consequences if I delete the `TXT` record?**

Our pages and articles will continue to be optimized for sharing on Facebook using the applicable `OG: Graph` tags and markup. So if a customer or subscriber were to post a link to one of our products or news articles, it will still be indexable and render pleasingly.

I have already spent several hours looking for answers on my own, but all the information I found naturally involved installing or troubleshooting domain-verification and OG: Graph tags. Hopefully, one of our members can share some relevant insights on this admittedly uncommon situation.

Comment: I would be very surprised if deleting Facebooks verification txt record wpuld impact SEO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about it at all. Feel free to delete the record as the only sense of keeping it has been lost since you left Facebook

Originally TXT record was intended as a place for human-readable notes, nowadays it mostly  turned into kinda stickers-board handling machine-readable data

As declared [in specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.3.14), the data of TXT record should be

> One or more character-strings

and

> TXT records are used to hold descriptive text. The semantics of the text depends on the domain where it is found

In short, this establishes no specific restrictions or purposes for TXT records, thus domain owners are free to use this type of records on their own minds as wide as they wish

Utilizing TXT records for automated domain verification is traditional [widely used  practice](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/verify-domain-txt) and maybe the most popular common case for these days, since this method delivers the fast and secure way to obtain the proof of ones ownership on domain name and related content for the remote service in no time, and this action can be completely automated

Due to the above each TXT record of that kind is valuable only for domain owner and the remote service, which supplies this record with data. And vice versa, TXT record of that kind is completely useless for anyone else - third-side can neither confirm nor deny if the record is corect, 'cause the origin is unknown

According to [Facebook manual](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/domain-verification/), your TXT record has been utilized by Facebook services for the one and only purpose to ascertain your ownnership for the domain to grant  incoming requests from your domain access to Facebook Business services

Answer (score 2):

No, Google doesn't track DNS records for search. I think it was in their webmaster chat recently when someone asked, but I couldn't find a reference to it anywhere.